# automatically open a group of files in Sublime Text 2

Tags: sublimetext2

Is there a way to open a group of files automatically in Sublime Text 2?  These files are stored in different folders.  From online posts and videos it looks like Projects within Sublime Text are for specifying which folders to include/exclude in a project, which is different than wanting to open a group of specific files.

Comment: Is there a reason why you're using the old Sublime Text 2 instead of 3?

Comment: It's on my old machine.  My new machine is in the works and will have the updated version installed.

Comment: What do you mean by automatically? Sublime should be able to open as many files as you want from the command line, for example.

Comment: Brilliant!  Thanks very much for the suggestion - it got me pointed in the right direction.  I ended up writing a .bat file to open specific files for a project.